# how to get a related value from a ForeignKey model django admin

Tags: django, model, save, admin

I've a model with a fk, but when save method I need get related value, e.g:

```
class Pedidos(models.Model):
    ped_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes, verbose_name='Cliente')
    ped_remetente = models.ForeignKey(Remetentes, verbose_name='Remetente')
    ped_produto = models.ForeignKey(Produtos, verbose_name='Produto')
    ped_data_pedido = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data Pedido')
    ped_quantidade = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Peso/Volume', max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    ped_key = models.IntegerField(unique=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Cod. Pedido')

class Pagamentos(models.Model):
    pag_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes, verbose_name='Cliente')
    pag_key_ped = models.ForeignKey(Pedidos, verbose_name='Cód. Pedido')
    pag_vencimento = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data Vencimento')
    pag_vlr_total = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Valor Total', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I need when I save model Pagamentos the value field: **pag_key_ped** receive **Pedidos.ped_key** value

How I do to access this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `pag_key_ped.ped_key`.

So:

```
>>> p = Pedidos(ped_key=1)
>>> p.save()

>>> pagamentos = Pagamentos()
>>> pagamentos.pag_key_ped = p
>>> pagamentos.save()

>>> print(pagamentos.pag_key_ped.ped_key)
[out] 1

>>> pagamentos.pag_key_ped = pagamentos.pag_key_ped.ped_key
>>> pagamentos.save()
```

HOWEVER!: This is a strange thing you want to do. `pag_key_ped` is already a ForeignKey and you want to override it with another ID. If there is no object with that ID, it will throw an `DoesNotExist` error.

Comment: how do this inside the django admim? Need override save method in Model?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ModelAdmin has a save_method that you can overwrite. Checkout the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model